# Condition parameter type does not match schema type

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamoDB called 'Contributors'. I have a primary composite key where the hash key is 'UserId' and the sort key is 'NoteId'. I want to query for all the items belonging to a particular hashkey.

Now if I use aws-cli, following command works:

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name Contributors \
--key-condition-expression 'UserId = :UserId' \
--expression-attribute-values '{
    ":UserId": {"N":"2"}
}'
```

But when I write the query in Node.js, neither of the below 2 param objects work:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Contributors",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#UserId = :UserId",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#UserId": "UserId"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":UserId": { "N": "2" }
    }
};
```

OR this:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Contributors",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#UserId = :UserId",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#UserId": "UserId"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":UserId": "2"
    }
};
```

I get the following error:

> ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid:
>   Condition parameter type does not match schema type

What should be the correct param object?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The following code should work. Just give the value without double quotes. The `DocumentClient` will automatically interpret the data type.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: "Contributors",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#UserId = :UserId",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#UserId": "UserId"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":UserId": 2
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: This solved it for me! Seems like the AWS SDK docs for Javascript refers to the AWS.DynamoDB() class. I had this problem because I was trying to implement the SDK docs examples with AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient().

Answer (score 45):

I had the issue because of passing the data type along with the value. Just remove the data type DocumentClient will automatically interpret the data type and it works:

**From:**

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
 ":UserId": { "S": req.query.status }
}
```

**To:**

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
 ":UserId": req.query.status
}
```

Comment: This does work, but it reduces code quality and you cannot use this query with the aws cli --cli-input-json option because data types aren't specified.

Comment: This worked for me. I tried sending `{"N":1}` and `{"N":"1"}` and even `{"S":"1"}`. None worked.

Comment: Why would they do that.

Comment: My hero!!!! I spent a lot of time following the correct practices and nothing worked, none documentation refers to that.

Answer (score 12):

Replacing:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

With:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB();
```

Instantly solved this problem for me.

Comment: This works, but makes breaks if you use docClient.get.  It also includes the types in the resulting document which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you came here and you are using Indexes, if your index is set to string and your data it's a Number, you need to delete that Index and create a new one with the correct data type. :)

Comment: I am having the same problem, but the index key is a string and I am querying the index with a string